# CSS change height of child name

Tags: css

How would i go about chaning this setting?

```
<div class="rsNav rsTabs">
```

I had tried:

```
.rsNav rsTabs {
    height: 100px;
}
```

and

```
.rsTabs {
    height: 100px;
}
```

But it does not change the div its in. I'm sure i am just over-thinking this! Ha.

Comment: Can you give us the link to your code or make a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your html too? I'm guessing there's something that's overwriting your css

Comment: you are missing a `.` before this `rsTabs` class

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.rsNav.rsTabs{ 
height:100px 
}
```

Comment: Ah i knew it was something easy! Thanks!

Comment: Yes ... and logic, an elem with a class: `div.rsNav`, or `.rsNav`, so, adding a class to this `div.rsNav.rsTabs`